# How do i access html input in a razor file, and save it into a c# variable?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have a .cshtml (Razor) file where i am trying to use System.Web.UI.Page.Request to access information from html input. i am developing in Visual studio 2015.

here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="createEvent">
@using System.Web;
@{   
    string title = Request["title"];
    string address = Request["address"];

    <p>
        You entered: <br />
        Your Title: @title <br />
        Your Address: @address
    </p>

}
```

With Html input:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs="">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" />
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address">
</md-input-container>

<md-button class="md-raised">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</md-button>
```

I have included System.Web in my references for the project, but it does not recognize "Request". Intellisense gives me the message: "The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context".

If i should not be trying to use "Request", how else could i get the input information into c# variables?

Comment: What type of project you've started with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *can* access the Request object via `Context.Request` in a view, you should rarely do so, certainly not to access values from form fields in the same view.

You need to wrap your input elements in a form with an action URL of a controller. The controller will receive the data from the form, and you can act on it there.

```
@using( Html.BeginForm( "Save", "MyController", FormMethod.Post ) )
{
    // your inputs here
}
```

1. Define a model that you want to populate.
2. Create a form for the model.
3. Submit the form to a controller action method that will automatically turn the HTTP Request into a model that can be read.

---

- [Models and Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Model Binding](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx)
- [Another Example of Getting Data from a Request](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol)